# Finding $x$ that makes $x^2 ≡ 1 (\mathrm{mod} \ n)$, when $n$ is a composite number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I find $x$, $( x > 1)$, that makes $x^2≡1 (\mathrm{mod} \ n)$, for any natural number $n$?

Comment: You want $n-1\equiv -1$.  That will always work; sometimes there are more.

Comment: http://www.numbertheory.org/php/squareroot.html and then CRT(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x^2 = 1 \mod n$, then $x^2 - 1 = 0\mod n$, so that $(x+1)(x-1) = 0\mod n$.

So given $n$, you need to find $x$ such that either

- $x = 1\mod n$, or
- $x = n-1\mod n$, or
- $x+1$ and $x-1$ are complementary factors of $n$.

Comment: $x+1$ and $x-1$ don't have to *be* complementary factors of $n$; they just have to be *multiples* of complementary factors. N.S.'s answer is more accurate than this one.

Answer (score 3):

If $p\neq 2$ is prime then

$$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p^k} \Leftrightarrow  p^k |(x-1)(x+1) \,.$$

As $\gcd(x+1,x+1)|2$, and $p \neq 2$, we have $p^k |(x-1)(x+1) \Leftrightarrow p^k | x-1$ or $p^k |x+1$.

If $p=2$ then $2^k |(x-1)(x+1)$ if and only if $2^{k-1}|(x-1)$ or $2^{k-1}|x+1$. This fact follows immediately from the observation that if $x^2-1$ is even, then both $x+1, x-1$ are even and $\gcd(x-1,x+1)=2$.

let $n=p_1^{k_1}....p_k^{k_k}$.

**Case 1** n is odd, or n is even but not multiple  of $4$. Then $x^2=1 \pmod n$ if and only if
$$x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p_i^{k_i}} \,;\, \forall 1 \leq i \leq k \,.$$

There are 2 possibilities for each prime; thus by the Chinese Remainder Theorem you get $2^k$ possible $x$. There are $2^k-1$ solutions $x \neq 1 \pmod{n}$ in this case.

**Case 2** n is multiple of 4. WLOG $p_1=2$.
Then $x^2=1 \pmod n$ if and only if
$$x \in \{ \pm 1 ; \pm 1 + 2^{k_1-1} \} \pmod{2^{k_1}} \,.$$
$$x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p_i^{k_i}} \,;\, \forall 2 \leq i \leq k \,.$$

There are 4 possibilities for $2$ and 2 possibilities for each prime; thus by the Chinese Remainder Theorem you get $2^{k+1}$ possible $x$. There are $2^{k+1}-1$ solutions $x \neq 1 \pmod{n}$ in this case.